# Adding an animation to a contact form

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, css-animations

If someone can set me on the correct path would be awesome! I've been searching and reading tutorials all night on something like this but I cant figure it out!

I am trying to do the same effect on the contact form as: http://clapat.ro/themes/newave/

As you scroll to the form it kind of bounces into the screen like a lot of the other elements on that page.

Also I am using bootstrap btw. Anyone? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the Fade in animation?

Comment: The skrollr.js library maybe ? http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/

Comment: Question isn't clear. Do you need the fade in/out effect on focus..?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes how the form fades in from the left

Comment: @Jahnux73 that's awesome! This actually looks perfect for what I need, just have to dive into it now!

Comment: @Dimitrov Check my example below. I provided the code and a jsfiddle for you

Comment: @WebDevRon as the user scrolls into the contact section, I think I have what I need though guys thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Sample of Some Jquery Code that you can use to make the effect you want.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 125) {
        $('#DivYouWantToAnimate').css('visibility', "visible").animate({ paddingLeft: "150px", opacity: '1' }, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Remember to set the default of the Div you want to animate to Visibility: Hidden; so it will show itself only when you scroll down.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDeq6/1/) with the Animation ( ScrollDOWN to see the effect )

EDIT: Remember you can change the effects of the jQuery so it looks more smooth than my example.

Comment: Ok awesome, this is what I was looking for!! The libraries above I will most likely use as well, but I was interested in how exactly it worked! Thank you great work, thanks everyone else as well!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do the same design as this website you can add "cool kitten" to your bootstrap stylesheet :
http://jalxob.com/cool-kitten/

For the animation, if you want to do something like a "bounce" you can use the JqueryUI bounce event : 
http://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/

Hope it'll help you

Comment: The cool kitten thing looks like it could work as well! thank you